# Page is not working in codeigniter showing page isn’t working

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to access page I get the following error message

This page isn’t working website is currently unable to handle this request.

> HTTP ERROR 500

other pages are working fine. at localhost this page working fine.
but on Linux hosting gives me an error.

i try to change config file

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

but its not working. my project is in subfolder.

Comment: Please paste your code here so that we can look into it

Comment: What's the error logs say? Me thinking its a .htaccess issue like follow links etc

Comment: Is it working with index.php?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:80/Foldername1/foldername2';
```

Comment: you are using phpmyadmin? or someother db

Comment: i am using phpmyadmin. but this code is not working

Comment: no my all page is working. but one page is not working showing error This page isn’t working

Comment: it is first page or ? please show as an image or something else then only i can try